# Regex with optional slashes in Sanic endpoints

Tags: python, regex, sanic

I want to do an API REST with Sanic (https://github.com/huge-success/sanic) and I'm stuck with the regular expressions.

I have this endpoint: `api/foo/<string_with_or_without_slashes>/bar/<string>/baz`

My python code is:

```
from sanic import Sanic                                                                                                                                                                  
from sanic.response import json                                                                                                                                                          

app = Sanic()                                                                                                                                                                            

@app.route('/api/foo/<foo_id:[^/].*?>/baz')                                                                                                                                              
async def test1(request, foo_id):                                                                                                                                                        
    return json({'test1': foo_id})                                                                                                                                                       

@app.route('/api/foo/<foo_id:[^/].*?>/bar/<bar_id>/baz')                                                                                                                                 
async def test2(request, foo_id, bar_id):                                                                                                                                                 
    return json({'test2': f'{foo_id}:{bar_id}'})                                                                                                                                         

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                               
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

If I do:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8000/api/foo/aa/bar/bb/baz
{"test1":"aa\/bar\/bb"}
```

Or `$ curl -i http://localhost:8000/api/foo/a/a/bar/bb/baz`.

It's always called `test1` when I want to call `test2` function.

Can you help me? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Your route works for me e.g. using: "/api/foo/hello/bar/world/baz/my_arg".

Comment: @user7217806 Thanks for your reply. I forgot to copy the problematic second endpoint. I already edited my answer to clarify my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both routes match your test requests, and as the first matching route is used (see this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/issues/395)) `test1` is executed.

Because your first route is more general than your second route, you could just define `test2` before `test1`:

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()

@app.route('/api/foo/<foo_id:[^/].*?>/bar/<bar_id>/baz')
async def test2(request, foo_id, bar_id):
    return json({'test2': f'{foo_id}:{bar_id}'})

@app.route('/api/foo/<foo_id:[^/].*?>/baz')
async def test1(request, foo_id):
    return json({'test1': foo_id})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```